# How to enlarge svg?

Tags: css, svg

I would like to zoom in a svg file, I don't know how to do it... Here is an

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/meteyepg/zq2gyhcz/>
```

I don't know if I should use some css or javascript.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use a tiny bit of Javascript to get the bounding box of your SVG contents, and change the SVG's `viewBox` to match it.

```js
// Get a reference to the SVG element
var  mymap = document.getElementById("mymap");
// Get the bounding box of the SVG contents
var  bbox = mymap.getBBox();
// Update the SVG's viewBox to match the bounding box
mymap.setAttribute("viewBox", [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" "));
```

```css
.pole { 
 fill           : #ffffff;
 fill-opacity   : 1;
 stroke         : black;
 stroke-opacity : 1;
 stroke-width   : 0.002;
}

.ring { 
 fill           : #ffffff;
 fill-opacity   : 1;
 stroke         : black;
 stroke-opacity : 1;
 stroke-width   : 0.002;
}

.multiple { 
 fill           : #ffffff;
 fill-opacity   : 1;
 stroke         : black;
 stroke-opacity : 1;
 stroke-width   : 0.002;
}

.rural { 
 fill           : #ffffff;
 fill-opacity   : 1;
 stroke         : black;
 stroke-opacity : 1;
 stroke-width   : 0.002;
}

polygon:hover{
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mymap" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="900" viewBox="-5.139017285 41.36275743 14.6988406 9.726639272" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1">

<g transform="translate(0,51.0893967) scale(1,-1) translate(0,-41.36275743)">
     
<g class="pole">

<polygon id="acheres" points="2.070157211,48.9463099 2.049002093,48.95709751 2.048854207,48.9592097 2.054221235,48.96897355 2.074400928,48.98480549 2.089784164,48.98802569 2.127452768,48.98905194 2.15264335,48.98610305 2.166353805,48.98147796 2.175023435,48.97324663 2.17815528,48.96351097 2.172905176,48.96386156 2.166086586,48.97684487 2.143263034,48.98570371 2.122047961,48.9870611 2.108124305,48.98229118 2.08706638,48.98405722 2.088198795,48.97714139 2.086659564,48.97377536 2.075634134,48.96617284 2.075675644,48.95231498 2.070157211,48.9463099"/>
<polygon id="78015 ANDRESY" points="2.048854207,48.9592097 2.045555519,48.96184542 2.035319459,48.96146674 2.044321964,48.982888 2.027031832,48.98907096 2.024722631,48.99561693 2.039921366,48.99626108 2.051868131,48.99164389 2.071883805,48.99339209 2.074400928,48.98480549 2.054221235,48.96897355 2.048854207,48.9592097"/>
<polygon id="78029 AUBERGENVILLE" points="1.852237514,48.93434872 1.849714323,48.93548469 1.834715378,48.95239141 1.839907316,48.96144411 1.836578224,48.97777058 1.817612632,48.97548071 1.828338802,48.98145852 1.854982163,48.98764225 1.864291998,48.95306196 1.869923799,48.94714359 1.856788747,48.94341268 1.852237514,48.93434872"/>
<polygon id="78031 AUFFREVILLE-BRASSEUIL" points="1.698418443,48.94366826 1.694269552,48.94577263 1.694827621,48.95237107 1.699335971,48.95775328 1.702412125,48.96364143 1.71922565,48.96143891 1.710223589,48.94938093 1.698418443,48.94366826"/>
<polygon id="78050 BAZOCHES-SUR-GUYONNE" points="1.858964194,48.75960125 1.848403461,48.76653391 1.839049995,48.76433855 1.8252923,48.76804486 1.834318253,48.77576993 1.83603796,48.78103966 1.856047377,48.78095409 1.871169124,48.79917719 1.872623707,48.79865124 1.866002617,48.78569027 1.870019835,48.77932409 1.863228557,48.77057069 1.869040323,48.76548981 1.867333741,48.76011268 1.858964194,48.75960125"/>
<polygon id="78073 BOIS-D'ARCY" points="2.050125421,48.79841285 2.030089508,48.79668691 1.994400509,48.79911726 1.996440552,48.81196934 2.000393008,48.81393622 2.024795939,48.81185322 2.048458423,48.80322054 2.050125421,48.79841285"/>
<polygon id="78092 BOUGIVAL" points="2.122449918,48.8507803 2.131714613,48.86237789 2.12435642,48.87438478 2.131966627,48.87097767 2.150387185,48.87086701 2.153764153,48.86440652 2.144469037,48.86181321 2.139863842,48.85590729 2.122449918,48.8507803"/>
<polygon id="78117 BUC" points="2.123282122,48.75352314 2.106444271,48.75735595 2.101493757,48.7564913 2.105472175,48.78074332 2.125014464,48.78083407 2.142014644,48.79233515 2.146395118,48.79084649 2.145853095,48.77074026 2.140552657,48.77117895 2.133318347,48.76597286 2.123282122,48.75352314"/>
<polygon id="78118 BUCHELAY" points="1.663794537,48.96964773 1.654335039,48.98203397 1.664047705,48.9948772 1.702551852,48.98923824 1.686219937,48.97849327 1.665963893,48.97028345 1.663794537,48.96964773"/>
<polygon id="78123 CARRIERES-SOUS-POISSY" points="2.049002093,48.95709751 2.04726846,48.9466248 2.036390265,48.93463986 2.022226504,48.93000152 2.008405583,48.93471735 2.00356966,48.94132326 2.008322701,48.94192925 2.028235253,48.95906235 2.03600794,48.95895423 2.035319459,48.96146674 2.045555519,48.96184542 2.048854207,48.9592097 2.049002093,48.95709751"/>
<polygon id="78124 CARRIERES-SUR-SEINE" points="2.174289314,48.89906693 2.161364085,48.90799743 2.160838792,48.92026953 2.167915863,48.92657813 2.180340271,48.9167443 2.19919119,48.9189672 2.200591009,48.90867933 2.174289314,48.89906693"/>
<polygon id="78126 LA CELLE-SAINT-CLOUD" points="2.120545689,48.83602536 2.110636174,48.84108762 2.110920421,48.84998467 2.119793951,48.8482695 2.122449918,48.8507803 2.139863842,48.85590729 2.144469037,48.86181321 2.153764153,48.86440652 2.15041165,48.85850089 2.159867593,48.8477212 2.150032316,48.84666241 2.145872523,48.83690143 2.120545689,48.83602536"/>
<polygon id="78133 CHAMBOURCY" points="2.037199223,48.87765472 2.020252868,48.88259867 1.998373859,48.89140232 2.012652512,48.89579287 2.02254073,48.89366157 2.026951436,48.89557715 2.027028641,48.91261147 2.039885102,48.91687015 2.052729085,48.90693576 2.054452747,48.8976681 2.037199223,48.87765472"/>
<polygon id="78138 CHANTELOUP-LES-VIGNES" points="2.035319459,48.96146674 2.03600794,48.95895423 2.028235253,48.95906235 2.023417014,48.97855594 2.026211825,48.98470279 2.020437441,48.99384643 2.024722631,48.99561693 2.027031832,48.98907096 2.044321964,48.982888 2.035319459,48.96146674"/>
<polygon id="78140 CHAPET" points="1.951517373,48.95469287 1.932478159,48.95816711 1.920774567,48.96868327 1.934534757,48.98243077 1.939088359,48.98090635 1.949439854,48.97979239 1.953586536,48.96994531 1.95573515,48.95682509 1.951517373,48.95469287"/>
<polygon id="78146 CHATOU" points="2.158314349,48.88060908 2.144932867,48.88338319 2.145855525,48.89364234 2.135995118,48.90591953 2.125952172,48.90766332 2.133703442,48.91164072 2.142580713,48.90449195 2.161364085,48.90799743 2.174289314,48.89906693 2.169348729,48.89581313 2.158314349,48.88060908"/>
<polygon id="78158 LE CHESNAY" points="2.148475928,48.82849269 2.140437002,48.82446883 2.136072645,48.81493967 2.131007668,48.81486698 2.114001309,48.82187448 2.112676125,48.82851124 2.120545689,48.83602536 2.145872523,48.83690143 2.148475928,48.82849269"/>
<polygon id="78160 CHEVREUSE" points="2.037642875,48.68022018 2.029656784,48.68454514 2.020820821,48.69645453 2.023426096,48.70319525 2.002901161,48.71409842 2.004349825,48.72082081 2.034230994,48.72594163 2.061828415,48.72302255 2.066560867,48.71761773 2.055518385,48.69981965 2.055658739,48.68678681 2.045836488,48.68678058 2.04255161,48.68069147 2.037642875,48.68022018"/>
<polygon id="78165 LES CLAYES-SOUS-BOIS" points="1.994400509,48.79911726 1.986479116,48.79968895 1.966898485,48.82179131 1.970086059,48.83487839 1.983641157,48.83353729 1.995914202,48.8272821 2.000393008,48.81393622 1.996440552,48.81196934 1.994400509,48.79911726"/>
<polygon id="78168 COIGNIERES" points="1.932428891,48.74171516 1.916481817,48.73356594 1.906655067,48.73529333 1.90328857,48.73824879 1.89559543,48.74255844 1.89348425,48.76517008 1.900973052,48.76556304 1.901068543,48.76813643 1.91621892,48.7586864 1.940190234,48.75667083 1.937122798,48.74830534 1.932428891,48.74171516"/>
<polygon id="78172 CONFLANS-SAINTE-HONORINE" points="2.074400928,48.98480549 2.071883805,48.99339209 2.071694219,49.00170884 2.084914921,49.01467871 2.107910568,49.00906964 2.12125682,49.01849327 2.126808839,49.00866906 2.121573868,48.99489922 2.127452768,48.98905194 2.089784164,48.98802569 2.074400928,48.98480549"/>
<polygon id="78190 CROISSY-SUR-SEINE" points="2.150387185,48.87086701 2.131966627,48.87097767 2.12435642,48.87438478 2.119794118,48.87811065 2.110267283,48.8874385 2.118188802,48.89077973 2.129363382,48.87664272 2.135559274,48.88533942 2.144932867,48.88338319 2.158314349,48.88060908 2.150387185,48.87086701"/>
<polygon id="78208 ELANCOURT" points="1.973475056,48.75341764 1.967799891,48.75699362 1.964447051,48.76210959 1.951944219,48.75937405 1.952045772,48.76515857 1.947364263,48.76588196 1.936505781,48.77993442 1.941237904,48.79154348 1.956870313,48.78927043 1.97004222,48.79986324 1.985935301,48.79964836 1.970907901,48.78565942 1.976015744,48.77230137 1.973507485,48.76560579 1.978059992,48.75963637 1.973475056,48.75341764"/>
<polygon id="78224 L'ETANG-LA-VILLE" points="2.070853017,48.85462684 2.069626391,48.85462631 2.059741675,48.85557434 2.044011732,48.86382297 2.036302563,48.86789829 2.046811515,48.87470976 2.058703418,48.87984932 2.063022551,48.87852516 2.077372254,48.87361815 2.080725077,48.87136854 2.070853017,48.85462684"/>
<polygon id="78227 EVECQUEMONT" points="1.936111079,49.01021473 1.919474003,49.01482328 1.931983413,49.01748915 1.937802165,49.02177633 1.945607277,49.02526232 1.954947812,49.02453465 1.957081174,49.02180147 1.951697073,49.0121594 1.936111079,49.01021473"/>
<polygon id="78238 FLINS-SUR-SEINE" points="1.88479865,48.94051087 1.871713506,48.94143164 1.869923799,48.94714359 1.864291998,48.95306196 1.854982163,48.98764225 1.864812509,48.989894 1.875786925,48.99236249 1.87795879,48.98228364 1.889532844,48.97582639 1.885978002,48.97341025 1.88479865,48.94051087"/>
<polygon id="78239 FOLLAINVILLE-DENNEMONT" points="1.708405265,49.00829511 1.670579803,49.0082598 1.674538185,49.0192123 1.683953366,49.01998137 1.696950308,49.03060002 1.707021648,49.02873044 1.711475849,49.03054994 1.723457162,49.04497658 1.732065796,49.05041846 1.735637867,49.04868454 1.730035338,49.01542362 1.708405265,49.00829511"/>
<polygon id="78242 FONTENAY-LE-FLEURY" points="2.048458423,48.80322054 2.024795939,48.81185322 2.034785407,48.82617208 2.047715943,48.82673445 2.052683141,48.83074929 2.059396428,48.8293992 2.070680908,48.82301168 2.060286579,48.81704828 2.048458423,48.80322054"/>
<polygon id="78251 FOURQUEUX" points="2.046811515,48.87470976 2.037199223,48.87765472 2.054452747,48.8976681 2.075082276,48.8874057 2.063022551,48.87852516 2.058703418,48.87984932 2.046811515,48.87470976"/>
<polygon id="78261 GAILLON-SUR-MONTCIENT" points="1.907059475,49.01225586 1.899708233,49.01401423 1.89733139,49.01713989 1.8818983,49.01954209 1.883462901,49.03262304 1.908522502,49.04802383 1.914081504,49.04583509 1.91247369,49.04161205 1.905083695,49.02556507 1.907059475,49.01225586"/>
<polygon id="78267 GARGENVILLE" points="1.792267113,48.96974226 1.80150436,48.98501553 1.797852557,49.00879269 1.799137585,49.01707007 1.820380621,49.011831 1.827651209,48.99619151 1.822835058,48.98315831 1.823799101,48.97980432 1.828338802,48.98145852 1.817612632,48.97548071 1.806854051,48.97102143 1.792267113,48.96974226"/>
<polygon id="78297 GUYANCOURT" points="2.101493757,48.7564913 2.088237895,48.75293689 2.078589752,48.7539242 2.068446544,48.7567148 2.05373553,48.76751859 2.055380119,48.77062573 2.046455005,48.77353201 2.044366015,48.77985644 2.053611708,48.79460892 2.070251387,48.78981062 2.105472175,48.78074332 2.101493757,48.7564913"/>
<polygon id="78299 HARDRICOURT" points="1.888038124,48.99843898 1.881078102,49.01064957 1.861712766,49.01411858 1.868558417,49.0180592 1.8818983,49.01954209 1.89733139,49.01713989 1.899708233,49.01401423 1.905287818,49.00485662 1.888038124,48.99843898"/>
<polygon id="78311 HOUILLES" points="2.19919119,48.9189672 2.180340271,48.9167443 2.167915863,48.92657813 2.182881354,48.93653752 2.198926853,48.93525192 2.204617626,48.92373373 2.19919119,48.9189672"/>
<polygon id="78314 ISSOU" points="1.785941217,48.9680416 1.785987787,48.97833042 1.771521698,48.98227507 1.775457151,48.98863755 1.778641441,48.99501918 1.795654192,49.00219675 1.797852557,49.00879269 1.80150436,48.98501553 1.792267113,48.96974226 1.785941217,48.9680416"/>
<polygon id="78321 JOUARS-PONTCHARTRAIN" points="1.89348425,48.76517008 1.889945589,48.77033624 1.885899951,48.80431637 1.885072705,48.80543298 1.894001107,48.80563285 1.893691576,48.80867012 1.898492104,48.80962289 1.914910943,48.80263145 1.941237904,48.79154348 1.936505781,48.77993442 1.933118416,48.78252166 1.923446727,48.7809328 1.909132627,48.78399606 1.89687527,48.77790206 1.901068543,48.76813643 1.900973052,48.76556304 1.89348425,48.76517008"/>
<polygon id="78322 JOUY-EN-JOSAS" points="2.138892811,48.74312204 2.131088572,48.7470771 2.128439648,48.75339899 2.154687726,48.76295996 2.145853095,48.77074026 2.146395118,48.79084649 2.161929189,48.78223199 2.190662977,48.77503676 2.187626751,48.77251573 2.19247239,48.76363515 2.189517467,48.75416195 2.17524948,48.75751815 2.161767486,48.75247729 2.151345551,48.75262854 2.138958105,48.74658544 2.138892811,48.74312204"/>
<polygon id="78327 JUZIERS" points="1.828338802,48.98145852 1.823799101,48.97980432 1.822835058,48.98315831 1.827651209,48.99619151 1.820380621,49.011831 1.830198857,49.01354581 1.831662682,49.0201878 1.851427707,49.01677241 1.851364451,49.0103599 1.864812509,48.989894 1.854982163,48.98764225 1.828338802,48.98145852"/>
<polygon id="78335 LIMAY" points="1.751753677,48.96735787 1.732468928,48.97789372 1.727270503,48.98486247 1.719248307,49.00099195 1.708405265,49.00829511 1.730035338,49.01542362 1.755444722,49.00603123 1.763656031,48.99874176 1.76219038,48.9896975 1.751987383,48.97412333 1.751753677,48.96735787"/>
<polygon id="78343 LES LOGES-EN-JOSAS" points="2.128439648,48.75339899 2.123282122,48.75352314 2.133318347,48.76597286 2.140552657,48.77117895 2.145853095,48.77074026 2.154687726,48.76295996 2.128439648,48.75339899"/>
<polygon id="78350 LOUVECIENNES" points="2.110636174,48.84108762 2.102663857,48.84274592 2.092697912,48.84617837 2.094520195,48.85266775 2.106944288,48.85695224 2.105603548,48.86677239 2.109398751,48.87283545 2.119794118,48.87811065 2.12435642,48.87438478 2.131714613,48.86237789 2.122449918,48.8507803 2.119793951,48.8482695 2.110920421,48.84998467 2.110636174,48.84108762"/>
<polygon id="78354 MAGNANVILLE" points="1.699335971,48.95775328 1.674925606,48.96169501 1.665907148,48.96983314 1.665963893,48.97028345 1.686219937,48.97849327 1.696707401,48.978167 1.697464994,48.96483789 1.702412125,48.96364143 1.699335971,48.95775328"/>
<polygon id="78356 MAGNY-LES-HAMEAUX" points="2.105537547,48.71658502 2.100744439,48.7154876 2.087142379,48.71989975 2.073239288,48.71662638 2.07237408,48.7232489 2.056440404,48.73229876 2.035267043,48.73241733 2.018838003,48.74127827 2.006299266,48.74626563 1.991707355,48.74756447 2.011238395,48.76196646 2.025542613,48.75585971 2.045187351,48.75133217 2.061005617,48.75215919 2.068446544,48.7567148 2.078589752,48.7539242 2.086181792,48.74528471 2.084628612,48.7291452 2.102764121,48.72294156 2.105537547,48.71658502"/>
<polygon id="78358 MAISONS-LAFFITTE" points="2.142430773,48.93512179 2.127853526,48.9431913 2.134469098,48.95584742 2.147465234,48.96525715 2.172905176,48.96386156 2.17815528,48.96351097 2.178105164,48.95976961 2.17314149,48.95329658 2.142430773,48.93512179"/>
<polygon id="78361 MANTES-LA-JOLIE" points="1.727270503,48.98486247 1.718442276,48.98269103 1.702551852,48.98923824 1.664047705,48.9948772 1.656069533,48.99738718 1.657976271,49.00611404 1.670579803,49.0082598 1.708405265,49.00829511 1.719248307,49.00099195 1.727270503,48.98486247"/>
<polygon id="78362 MANTES-LA-VILLE" points="1.71922565,48.96143891 1.702412125,48.96364143 1.697464994,48.96483789 1.696707401,48.978167 1.686219937,48.97849327 1.702551852,48.98923824 1.718442276,48.98269103 1.727270503,48.98486247 1.732468928,48.97789372 1.729985016,48.96828047 1.723572117,48.96297818 1.71922565,48.96143891"/>
<polygon id="78367 MAREIL-MARLY" points="2.077372254,48.87361815 2.063022551,48.87852516 2.075082276,48.8874057 2.087831431,48.88441872 2.091815253,48.88587898 2.08422244,48.8787162 2.077372254,48.87361815"/>
<polygon id="78372 MARLY-LE-ROI" points="2.092697912,48.84617837 2.081046982,48.85312265 2.070853017,48.85462684 2.080725077,48.87136854 2.077372254,48.87361815 2.08422244,48.8787162 2.097451381,48.88014772 2.101094624,48.8855353 2.104393405,48.872933 2.109398751,48.87283545 2.105603548,48.86677239 2.106944288,48.85695224 2.094520195,48.85266775 2.092697912,48.84617837"/>
<polygon id="78382 MAURECOURT" points="2.071883805,48.99339209 2.051868131,48.99164389 2.039921366,48.99626108 2.024722631,48.99561693 2.02361373,48.99790106 2.026444957,49.00070281 2.046501654,49.00185304 2.064428879,49.00820803 2.071694219,49.00170884 2.071883805,48.99339209"/>
<polygon id="78383 MAUREPAS" points="1.940190234,48.75667083 1.91621892,48.7586864 1.901068543,48.76813643 1.89687527,48.77790206 1.909132627,48.78399606 1.923446727,48.7809328 1.933118416,48.78252166 1.936505781,48.77993442 1.947364263,48.76588196 1.952045772,48.76515857 1.951944219,48.75937405 1.940190234,48.75667083"/>
<polygon id="78384 MEDAN" points="1.969741349,48.94467954 1.969467129,48.9461161 1.979300104,48.95851188 1.996151247,48.96706266 2.002521172,48.95399492 1.99601125,48.94885046 1.980861352,48.94853376 1.978490145,48.94551884 1.969741349,48.94467954"/>
<polygon id="78396 LE MESNIL-LE-ROI" points="2.113204846,48.90633754 2.104127722,48.90740316 2.110353346,48.92071469 2.122239694,48.93202586 2.122791996,48.94217413 2.127853526,48.9431913 2.142430773,48.93512179 2.123833692,48.92247777 2.113204846,48.90633754"/>
<polygon id="78397 LE MESNIL-SAINT-DENIS" points="1.971530094,48.72094724 1.963558246,48.72533081 1.961916096,48.73476128 1.947876824,48.73370288 1.932428891,48.74171516 1.937122798,48.74830534 1.956509072,48.74880015 1.958146374,48.75536268 1.967799891,48.75699362 1.973475056,48.75341764 1.991707355,48.74756447 1.987763563,48.74542631 1.988680127,48.72900041 1.971530094,48.72094724"/>
<polygon id="78401 MEULAN-EN-YVELINES" points="1.881045108,48.99377858 1.888038124,48.99843898 1.905287818,49.00485662 1.899708233,49.01401423 1.907059475,49.01225586 1.914951705,49.01598751 1.919474003,49.01482328 1.936111079,49.01021473 1.93710153,49.00657244 1.881045108,48.99377858"/>
<polygon id="78403 MEZY-SUR-SEINE" points="1.864812509,48.989894 1.851364451,49.0103599 1.851427707,49.01677241 1.859255155,49.01396935 1.861712766,49.01411858 1.881078102,49.01064957 1.888038124,48.99843898 1.881045108,48.99377858 1.875786925,48.99236249 1.864812509,48.989894"/>
<polygon id="78418 MONTESSON" points="2.120242856,48.90320578 2.113204846,48.90633754 2.123833692,48.92247777 2.142430773,48.93512179 2.160838792,48.92026953 2.161364085,48.90799743 2.142580713,48.90449195 2.133703442,48.91164072 2.125952172,48.90766332 2.120242856,48.90320578"/>
<polygon id="78423 MONTIGNY-LE-BRETONNEUX" points="2.025542613,48.75585971 2.011238395,48.76196646 2.00890823,48.7678926 2.022284832,48.78526336 1.994400509,48.79911726 2.030089508,48.79668691 2.050125421,48.79841285 2.053611708,48.79460892 2.044366015,48.77985644 2.046455005,48.77353201 2.055380119,48.77062573 2.05373553,48.76751859 2.04993104,48.76946719 2.025542613,48.75585971"/>
<polygon id="78440 LES MUREAUX" points="1.920774567,48.96868327 1.915877441,48.97032981 1.89733232,48.97974739 1.889532844,48.97582639 1.87795879,48.98228364 1.875786925,48.99236249 1.881045108,48.99377858 1.93710153,49.00657244 1.946468883,49.00638525 1.939088359,48.98090635 1.934534757,48.98243077 1.920774567,48.96868327"/>
<polygon id="78442 NEAUPHLE-LE-CHATEAU" points="1.914910943,48.80263145 1.898492104,48.80962289 1.893691576,48.80867012 1.888957982,48.80905796 1.901268932,48.82196179 1.913066136,48.81993795 1.914910943,48.80263145"/>
<polygon id="78443 NEAUPHLE-LE-VIEUX" points="1.872623707,48.79865124 1.871169124,48.79917719 1.841755255,48.80062273 1.847901304,48.81270786 1.841537491,48.82881842 1.846622179,48.82866969 1.851510558,48.83433821 1.865603069,48.83161251 1.874862143,48.83437128 1.865896017,48.82253097 1.868949473,48.81300779 1.885072705,48.80543298 1.885899951,48.80431637 1.875821511,48.80504951 1.872623707,48.79865124"/>
<polygon id="78466 ORGEVAL" points="1.981887669,48.90029289 1.971601492,48.8934148 1.953756576,48.89566153 1.93409451,48.9046347 1.931973587,48.90760169 1.942011279,48.91383338 1.969741349,48.94467954 1.978490145,48.94551884 1.982363841,48.92896815 1.998111832,48.92840837 2.008618147,48.9206985 1.979890821,48.90334271 1.981887669,48.90029289"/>
<polygon id="78481 LE PECQ" points="2.08422244,48.8787162 2.091815253,48.88587898 2.09925133,48.89039595 2.104127722,48.90740316 2.113204846,48.90633754 2.120242856,48.90320578 2.113065031,48.89933065 2.118188802,48.89077973 2.110267283,48.8874385 2.107096912,48.88940247 2.101094624,48.8855353 2.097451381,48.88014772 2.08422244,48.8787162"/>
<polygon id="78490 PLAISIR" points="1.985935301,48.79964836 1.97004222,48.79986324 1.956870313,48.78927043 1.941237904,48.79154348 1.914910943,48.80263145 1.913066136,48.81993795 1.917838586,48.82034101 1.921737091,48.8261236 1.930890041,48.8261788 1.94325826,48.83696487 1.968792679,48.83483127 1.970086059,48.83487839 1.966898485,48.82179131 1.986479116,48.79968895 1.985935301,48.79964836"/>
<polygon id="78498 POISSY" points="1.998373859,48.89140232 1.981887669,48.90029289 1.979890821,48.90334271 2.008618147,48.9206985 2.016906453,48.92405837 2.008405583,48.93471735 2.022226504,48.93000152 2.036390265,48.93463986 2.04726846,48.9466248 2.049002093,48.95709751 2.070157211,48.9463099 2.063219382,48.94111182 2.054601989,48.92550387 2.044986903,48.92290949 2.039885102,48.91687015 2.027028641,48.91261147 2.022166134,48.91360612 2.014347784,48.90495328 2.001322658,48.89979101 1.995659511,48.89423956 1.998373859,48.89140232"/>
<polygon id="78501 PORCHEVILLE" points="1.762926635,48.96680814 1.751753677,48.96735787 1.751987383,48.97412333 1.76219038,48.9896975 1.775457151,48.98863755 1.771521698,48.98227507 1.785987787,48.97833042 1.785941217,48.9680416 1.762926635,48.96680814"/>
<polygon id="78502 LE PORT-MARLY" points="2.109398751,48.87283545 2.104393405,48.872933 2.101094624,48.8855353 2.107096912,48.88940247 2.110267283,48.8874385 2.119794118,48.87811065 2.109398751,48.87283545"/>
<polygon id="78524 ROCQUENCOURT" points="2.112676125,48.82851124 2.100600376,48.82413987 2.091738803,48.82380307 2.08912012,48.82633746 2.102663857,48.84274592 2.110636174,48.84108762 2.120545689,48.83602536 2.112676125,48.82851124"/>
<polygon id="78545 SAINT-CYR-L'ECOLE" points="2.070251387,48.78981062 2.053611708,48.79460892 2.050125421,48.79841285 2.048458423,48.80322054 2.060286579,48.81704828 2.070680908,48.82301168 2.083174638,48.81895285 2.070251387,48.78981062"/>
<polygon id="78551 SAINT-GERMAIN-EN-LAYE" points="2.091815253,48.88587898 2.087831431,48.88441872 2.075082276,48.8874057 2.054452747,48.8976681 2.052729085,48.90693576 2.039885102,48.91687015 2.044986903,48.92290949 2.054601989,48.92550387 2.063219382,48.94111182 2.070157211,48.9463099 2.075675644,48.95231498 2.075634134,48.96617284 2.086659564,48.97377536 2.088198795,48.97714139 2.08706638,48.98405722 2.108124305,48.98229118 2.122047961,48.9870611 2.143263034,48.98570371 2.166086586,48.97684487 2.172905176,48.96386156 2.147465234,48.96525715 2.134469098,48.95584742 2.127853526,48.9431913 2.122791996,48.94217413 2.122239694,48.93202586 2.110353346,48.92071469 2.104127722,48.90740316 2.09925133,48.89039595 2.091815253,48.88587898"/>
<polygon id="78575 SAINT-REMY-LES-CHEVREUSE" points="2.082078805,48.68545492 2.069763142,48.68893057 2.066511581,48.68689924 2.055658739,48.68678681 2.055518385,48.69981965 2.066560867,48.71761773 2.07237408,48.7232489 2.073239288,48.71662638 2.087142379,48.71989975 2.100744439,48.7154876 2.105537547,48.71658502 2.107693289,48.71770753 2.110332693,48.71438114 2.097183445,48.70052006 2.097852608,48.6940307 2.089331408,48.69804071 2.082078805,48.68545492"/>
<polygon id="78576 SAINT-REMY-L'HONORE" points="1.90328857,48.73824879 1.873847305,48.73251466 1.853383382,48.73309341 1.853274633,48.7498142 1.858964194,48.75960125 1.867333741,48.76011268 1.869040323,48.76548981 1.882620924,48.76669701 1.889945589,48.77033624 1.89348425,48.76517008 1.89559543,48.74255844 1.90328857,48.73824879"/>
<polygon id="78586 SARTROUVILLE" points="2.160838792,48.92026953 2.142430773,48.93512179 2.17314149,48.95329658 2.205858347,48.94974074 2.206092558,48.94065943 2.198926853,48.93525192 2.182881354,48.93653752 2.167915863,48.92657813 2.160838792,48.92026953"/>
<polygon id="78609 TESSANCOURT-SUR-AUBETTE" points="1.907059475,49.01225586 1.905083695,49.02556507 1.91247369,49.04161205 1.937802165,49.02177633 1.931983413,49.01748915 1.919474003,49.01482328 1.914951705,49.01598751 1.907059475,49.01225586"/>
<polygon id="78621 TRAPPES" points="1.991707355,48.74756447 1.973475056,48.75341764 1.978059992,48.75963637 1.973507485,48.76560579 1.976015744,48.77230137 1.970907901,48.78565942 1.985935301,48.79964836 1.986479116,48.79968895 1.994400509,48.79911726 2.022284832,48.78526336 2.00890823,48.7678926 2.011238395,48.76196646 1.991707355,48.74756447"/>

</g>

</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Note that I have had to reduce the size of your SVG in order to get under the 30000 character answer limit.

Comment: It's exactly what I searching for ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo of what exactly you need [demo Tiger](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/inline.html)

Reference the [svg-pan-zoom.js](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/dist/svg-pan-zoom.min.js) file from your HTML document. Then call the init method:

```
var panZoomTiger = svgPanZoom('#demo-tiger');
// or
var svgElement = document.querySelector('#demo-tiger')
var panZoomTiger = svgPanZoom(svgElement)
```

First argument to function should be a CSS selector of SVG element or a DOM Element.

If you want to override the defaults, you can optionally specify one or more arguments:

```
svgPanZoom('#demo-tiger', {
  viewportSelector: '.svg-pan-zoom_viewport'
, panEnabled: true
, controlIconsEnabled: false
, zoomEnabled: true
, dblClickZoomEnabled: true
, mouseWheelZoomEnabled: true
, preventMouseEventsDefault: true
, zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.2
, minZoom: 0.5
, maxZoom: 10
, fit: true
, contain: false
, center: true
, refreshRate: 'auto'
, beforeZoom: function(){}
, onZoom: function(){}
, beforePan: function(){}
, onPan: function(){}
, onUpdatedCTM: function(){}
, customEventsHandler: {}
, eventsListenerElement: null
});
```

For more you can refer to : https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom

Comment: It works perfectly ! Just put this code :

(`<script src="http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/dist/svg-pan-zoom.min.js"></script>
<script>

 var svgElement   = document.querySelector('#departement');

  panZoomTiger = svgPanZoom(svgElement);
  panZoomTiger.zoomAtPoint(11, {x: 475, y: 260});
  panZoomTiger.disableZoom();
  panZoomTiger.disablePan();

</script>`)